# Can not access network drives after installing new wireless router

Tags: networking, domain, router, wifi

My new wireless router is blocking access to company network drives. If i remove the router and connect directly to company network, i am able to access mapped network drives, but as soon as i connect throught new router network drives cannot be accesed anymore.

Which settings should i change on my router?

Comment: i found solution for my problem. It was WAN settings. My router was creating a new DHCP configuration that somehow messed up connection with domain. After i switched WAN connection to disabled it started to work fine. I can access network drives now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting wirelessly to the wireless router which is then wired to the company network?

If that is the case the network will probably not have a route back to your PC because it will be picking up an IP address from the wireless router which will be using a range unknown the the network as a whole.